# How to fix IntelliJ 2018.1 code format

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, jetbrains-ide

Since update to new IntelliJ I have problem with code format in Java. Here is some examples (dummy code):

```
IntStream.of(0, 10).map(someoperanddummy -> Optional.of(someoperanddummy += 1).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Can not find object definition with id "))).filter(value -> value % 2 == 0).forEach(value -> System.out.println());
```

After reformat using <kbd>CMD + Option + L</kbd> in IntelliJ I've got:

```
IntStream.of(0, 10).map(someoperanddummy -> Optional.of(someoperanddummy += 1).orElseThrow(() -> new
                RuntimeException("Can not find object definition with id "))).filter(value -> value % 2 == 0)
                .forEach(value -> System.out.println());
```

Or another example (why bracket is on the separate line?):

```
        Example<BusinessObjectDefinition> example = Example.of(BusinessObjectDefinition.builder().name
            (businessObjectDefinition.getName()).build());
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the margin changed to default value: you can edit the right margin by pressing ctrl+alt+s ( to go to **settings** ) and search for **right margin**. Then go to **Code Style** -> **Java** -> **Wrapping and Braces** -> **Right Margin (columns)**. Increase to have longer code lines. 
There are also custom settings there to configure what to do with lambas ( **Keep when reformatting**)

Comment: Unfortunetly not. It's not a problem with margin. Note that the word "new" has been on the previous line. That the bracket was opened in the next line. I did not have such problems with the previous version.

Comment: There are other options in the same menu that might help you. After changing some settings you can save this to a custom scheme for future use ( should this problem occure again in a future update )